# Grep doesn't work with both -v and -A/B

Tags: grep

So I'm trying to use grep with both -v argument and -A argument.

So my file has text like:

```
This error
-this
-this
-that
[text I want]
This error
-asd
-asfag
-adsfhs
[text I want]
[text I want]
This error
-asdgsda
-asdgg
-gasdg
```

After a tail, I found out that this log file is filled with the same `This error` followed by 3 lines construct, and I can easily find them by using `grep -A3 'This error'`, this shows me the error and the 3 lines after it.

But I want to see everything OTHER than that, hence the -v argument, but it doesn't work. When I do `grep -v -A3 'This error'` it returns the whole file, like grep didn't even work at all.

What is the problem here?

Comment: "The problem" is, that grep checks for every line whether it contains "This error" or not. And if not, it prints out the the next 3 lines whatever they contains (But grep avoid printing the same line multiple times). So it also output lines you don't want to see.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `sed` instead of `grep`, it provides a nice solution:

```
sed -e '/This error/,+3d' myfile
```

This removes the line containing the string `This error` and the following three lines, but outputs everything else.  This `sed` command requires GNU `sed` (the `+3` address is an extension).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -vM  'This error\n.*\n.*\n.*' file
```

It will give output:

```
[text I want]
[text I want]
[text I want]
```

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686147/9235408

Answer (score 0):

As finswimmer [pointed out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530368/grep-doesnt-work-with-both-v-and-a-b#comment981507_530368), your `grep -v` command would output the three lines after each line that does not match the text `This error`.  This is not what you want.

Using standard `sed`:

```
sed '/This error/{ N;N;N; d; }' file
```

This looks for the text `This error` in the file, and when this is found it reads the next three lines as well, and deletes all four lines.  All other lines are outputted.